# KnpMenuBundle - how can i set an icon class to each elements of menu?

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I want to my view code looks like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="path/to/action">
            <i class="icon-class"></i>
            <span class="title">Title</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I create menu elements by Menu Builder:

```
class Builder extends ContainerAware
{
    public function adminMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
            'route' => 'admin_dashboard',
        ));

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

I have overwritten view with following code (knp_menu.html.twig):

```
{% block linkElement %}
    {% import _self as knp_menu %}
    <a href="{{ item.uri }}"{{ knp_menu.attributes(item.linkAttributes) }}>
        <i class="icon-class"></i>
        <span class="title">{{ block('label') }}</span>
    </a>
{% endblock %}
```

How can i pass a value of icon class name to `<i>` element in method adminMenu(), in Builder class? What is the most simple way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add any attribute you want with

```
$menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
    'route' => 'admin_dashboard',
))->setAttribute('icon', 'icon-class');
```

then

```
{{ item.attribute('icon') }}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest the use of `extras` instead of `attributes`, because `attributes` is used to render the `li` element's attributes.

```php
$menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
    'uri' => '#',
))->setAttribute('icon', 'icon-class');
```

and

```twig
{{ item.attribute('icon') }}
```

will probably be rendered as:

```html
<li icon="icon-class"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-icon-class" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Whereas:

```php
$menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
    'uri' => '#',
))->setExtra('icon', 'icon-class');
```

and

```twig
{{ item.extra('icon') }}
```

Will probably just be rendered as:

```html
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-icon-class" aria-hidden="true"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095287/2106834.

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted as the final answer. In my version of KnpMenuBundle the accepted one does not even work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
$menu->addChild('Home', ['route' => 'home_page'])
        ->setAttribute('icon', 'fa fa-home');
```